# Data Transfer Job Fails with Error: "Cannot load CSV data with a nested schema"

Tags: google-bigquery, data-transfer

I created a Data Transfer Job with the following information:
Datasource - Cloud Storage (Bucket with Datastore export data)
Source - Table on Bigquery
Run On-Demand

Fails with error: Cannot load CSV data with a nested schema

Cannot figure out how to resolve this

Comment: I'm facing the same, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: What I figured out, after talking to a Data Specialist, is that there is no automatic way to refresh the data when the source is Datastore.
What I ended up needing to do is to redo the whole process from scratch. You need to "delete" the buckets on Could Storage, redo the exports, then "delete" the tables on BigQuery and re-create them.
Make sure to name the BQ tables the same as before so your Data Studio report doesn't break.